# Zend Framework Data Access Layer (DAL)

Tags: php, oop, zend-framework, data-access-layer, dao

Looking through several tutorials and books regarding data access in Zend Framework, it seems as if most people do data access within their models (Active Record Pattern) or even controllers. I strongly disagree with that. Therefore I want to have a Data Access Layer (DAL) so that my domain layer remains portable by not having any "ZF stuff" in it. I have searched around but have not really found exactly what I wanted. Heads up: I am new to ZF.

**DAL structure**

So, the first problem is where to place the Data Access Layer. While it could certainly be placed within the `library` folder and adding a namespace to the autoloader, that does not seem logical as it is specific to my application (so the `applications` folder is suitable). I am using a modular structure. I am thinking of using the below structure:

`/application/modules/default/dal/`

However, I am not sure how include this folder so that I can access the classes within the controllers (without using includes/requires). If anyone knows how to accomplish this, that would be super! Any other ideas are of course also welcome.

The idea is to have my controllers interact with the Data Access Objects (DAO). Then the DAOs use models that can then be returned to the controllers. By doing this, I can leave my models intact.

**Implementation**

In other languages, I have previously implemented DAOs per model, e.g. `DAL_User`. This resulted in an awful lot of DAO classes. Is there a smarter way to do this (using a single class does not seem easy with foreign keys)?

I would also appreciate suggestions on how to implement my DAO classes in ZF. I have not spent an awful lot of time reading about all of the components available for database interaction, so any ideas are very welcome. I suspect that there is something smarter than standard PDO available (which probably uses PDO internally, though). Name drops would be sufficient.

Sorry for the many questions. I just need a push in the right direction.

Comment: I like this question, but the scope is huge. You are covering several topics and as a result your answers will be incomplete.

Comment: @RockyFord I agree. I wanted to make it more precise, but I thought that everything was kind of connected. But now that I think about it, the theoretical part about the structure and then the actual implementation could be two different questions.

Comment: gotta give @Keyne credit for a very valiant attempt to condense this down to a reasonable answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the first thing you have to take into account when dealing with the `Data Access Layer`, is that this layer **also have sub-layers**, it's unusual to find folders called "dal" in modern frameworks (I'm taking as basis both Zend Framework and Symfony).

Second, about `ActiveRecord`, you must be aware that by default Zend Frameworks **doesn't implement it**. Most of the tutorials take the easiest path to teach new concepts. With simple examples, the amount of **business logic** is minimal, so instead of adding another layer of complexity (mapping between database and model's objects) they compose the `domain layer` (model) with two basic patterns: [Table Data Gateway](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/tableDataGateway.html) and [Row Data Gateway](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/rowDataGateway.html). Which is enough information for a beginner to start.

> After analyzing it, you will see some similarity between **ActiveRecord**
>   and **Row Data Gateway** patterns. The main difference is that
>   ActiveRecord objects (persistable entities) **carries business logic** and
>   Row Data Gateway **only represents a row** in the database. If you add
>   business logic on a object representing a database row, then it will
>   become an **ActiveRecord** object.

Additionally, following the Zend Framework **Quick Start**, [on the domain model section](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.create-model.html), you will realize that there's a third component, which uses the [Data Mapper Pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html).

So, if the main purpose of your `DAL` is to map data between business objects (model) and your storage, the responsibility of this task **is delegated to the Data Mappers** as follows:

```
class Application_Model_GuestbookMapper
{

    public function save(Application_Model_Guestbook $guestbook);

    public function find($id);

    public function fetchAll();

}
```

Those methods will interact with the `Database Abstraction Layer` and populate the domain objects with the data. Something along this lines:

```
public function find($id, Application_Model_Guestbook $guestbook)
{

    $result = $this->getDbTable()->find($id);

    if (0 == count($result)) {

        return;

    }

    $row = $result->current();

    $guestbook->setId($row->id)

              ->setEmail($row->email)

              ->setComment($row->comment)

              ->setCreated($row->created);

}
```

As you can see, the `Data Mappers` interacts with a [Zend_Db_Table](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.html) instance, which uses the **Table Data Gateway Pattern**. On the other hand, the `$this->getDbTable->find()` returns instances of the [Zend_Db_Table_Row](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.row.html), which implements the **Row Data Gateway Pattern** (it's an object representing a database row).

> Tip: The `domain object` itself, the `guestbook`
>   entity, **was not created** by the find() method on the DataMapper,
>   instead, the idea is that **object creation is a task of factories**
>   and you must inject the dependency in order to achieve the so called
>   [Dependency Inversion Principle (DIP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) (part of the SOLID principles). But that's
>   another subject, out of the scope of the question. I suggest you 
>   to access the following link http://youtu.be/RlfLCWKxHJ0

The mapping stuff begins here:

```
$guestbook->setId($row->id)
          ->setEmail($row->email)
          ->setComment($row->comment)
          ->setCreated($row->created);
```

So far, I think I have answered your main question, your structure will be as following:

```
application/models/DbTable/Guestbook.php
application/models/Guestbook.php
application/models/GuestbookMapper.php
```

So, as in the ZF Quick Start:

```
class GuestbookController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

    public function indexAction()

    {
        $guestbook = new Application_Model_GuestbookMapper();

        $this->view->entries = $guestbook->fetchAll();

    }

}
```

Maybe you want to have a separated folder for the data mappers. Just change:

```
application/models/GuestbookMapper.php
```

to

```
application/models/DataMapper/GuestbookMapper.php
```

The class name will be

```
class Application_Model_DataMapper_GuestbookMapper
```

I've seen that you want to separate your `domain model objects` into modules. It's possible too, all you need is to follow the ZF's directory and [namespace guidelines for modules](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.modular.html).

> Final tip: I've spent **a lot of time** coding my own data mappers for
>   finally realize that it's **nightmare to maintain** the object mapping when
>   your application grows with a lot of correlated entities. (i.e Account
>   objects that contain references to users objects, users that contain
>   roles, and so on) It's not so easy to write the mapping stuff at this
>   point. So I strongly recommend you, if you really want a true
>   object-relational mapper, to first study how legacy frameworks perform
>   such tasks and perhaps use it. 
>   So, take some spare time with [Doctrine 2](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/index.html), which is the
>   one of the best so far (IMO) using the **DataMapper pattern**.

That's it. You still can use your `/dal` directory for storing the DataMappers, just [register the namespace](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.loader.autoloader.html), so that the auto loader can find it.

Comment: My controller cannot find my mapper class: `$userMapper = new Application_Model_DataMappers_UserMapper();`. The path to the class is: `/application/modules/default/models/DataMappers/UserMapper.php`. Also, in the mapper example you gave, shouldn't the `$guestbook` parameter of the `find` method be passed by reference?

Comment: @andy124 Not sure if I understand you. About the classes not loading, you need to make some testing with the zf namespaces, try out put the mapper at the same directory level and see if it works first.

Comment: @Keyne +1 for a great and detailed write-up.  One note:  ZF has a default directory structure for mapper classes built in. `\modules\[modulename]\models\Mappers\Guestbook.php` and should map to a class name of `class [Modulename]_Model_Mapper_Guestbook`.  I don't believe this is documented well.

Comment: @jmbertucci Thank you. Didn't notice that, as I'm currently using Doctrine. Maybe that's the reason Andy124 is not getting the mapper from controllers.

Comment: @jmbertucci Thank you! That worked! I haven't seen that mentioned anywhere. Now that my controller can find my mapper, I am trying to instantiate the DB table class from within my mapper, like this: `new Default_Model_DbTable_User()`. The class is located at `/application/modules/default/models/DbTable/UserTable.php`. I have tried with various class names, but without luck.

Comment: @andy124 The mapper directory was something I stumbled upon once-upon-a-time. I recall it not being well documented. As for your problem, the file name should only be the name of the final class.  Drop the `Table` part of your file name. Ie. `Default_Model_DbTable_User()` => `.../models/DbTable/User.php`.  If that wasn't the issue, it would be best to open a new question about this specific issue so you can post more error code and make it easier for people to see and help with it. =)

Comment: @Keyne If you don't mind me asking an additional question... This technique seems straightforward for 1:1 mappings (or otherwise with views), but for a normalized database, this is not always the case. As you also mentioned, it adds some complexity. Would this solution still be good when joining tables? I saw some ways people have done it, but it did not seem so straightforward. And how about stored procedures? Thank you in advance! And also thank you for a very well written answer.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you *should* have a gateway abstraction (not just Database access) per model.  A DAO is not enough.  What if you need to get the data from the cloud at some point?  This is quickly coming a reality.  If you abstract your gateway logic into something generic and then implement it using a database you can have the best of both worlds.

The implementation of a specific gateway interface could use a generic data mapper if you so chose. I work for a small company and have always just created my implementation using PDO.  This lets me be close enough to the database to deal with any interesting bits of SQL I might need but am able to support a very abstracted interface.

---

I have not used the Zend Framework at all.  I do not know if they have data-mapper tools that could help you implement the gateway interfaces.

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you mean. If you could please elaborate what you mean by gateway abstraction, that would be appreciated. I guess I am a rookie. You make a good point of not being tied to a database. But wouldn't simply using interfaces do the job?

Comment: @andy124 Don't worry about gateway abstraction in ZF it's done pretty much by default in a ZF MVC. When Quickstart had you create `Application_Model_DbTable_Guestbook` that is a gateway to that one table and encapsulates the Sqlite PDO adapter or whatever adapter you used.

Comment: @andy124 The gateway is basically a means to get and retrieve data where you have absolutely no idea how it gets the data.  It could be from a database, from the cloud, from a file system . . . doesn't matter.  The gateway *is* an interface.